# app is crashing. when i'm downloading second index of video from custom table cell

Tags: ios

i'm developing a app from downloading video. it's working good.when i'm downloading first index video. but when i'm downloading except this video. it's crashing. my error showing is:

> 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'" ***

```
     -(void)clickbtn:(id)sender{

        btnTag =[sender tag];
         NSLog(@"%d",btnTag);

        NSLog(@"tag number is = %ld",(long)[sender tag]);

        NSString *vedioUrl =[[allData objectAtIndex:btnTag]valueForKey:@"video"];
        NSLog(@"%@",vedioUrl);
       NSString *encodeUrl = [vedioUrl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:
                             NSASCIIStringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"%@",encodeUrl);


          NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:encodeUrl];
        NSLog(@"%@",url);
        self.downloadManager = [[DownloadManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self];
        self.downloadManager.maxConcurrentDownloads = 4;
        [self.downloadManager addDownloadWithFilename:downloadFilename URL:url];



        self.startDate = [NSDate date];
        [self.downloadManager start];

         UIButton *button1 = (UIButton*)sender;
        NSLog(@"%@",button1);
        CGPoint buttonPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero
                                               toView:self.Table];

        NSIndexPath *clickedIP = [self.Table indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition];
        NSLog(@"%@",clickedIP);

        DownloadCell *cell = (DownloadCell *) [self.Table cellForRowAtIndexPath:clickedIP];
        NSLog(@"%@",cell);



        Download *download = self.downloadManager.downloads[clickedIP.row];

        NSLog(@"%@",download);

           if (download.isDownloading)

        {

           [self updateProgressViewForIndexPath:clickedIP download:download];
        }
        else

         {
                 cell.progressView.hidden = YES;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying get value from array that contain either only one value at `0 index` or that particular array has been null. and when you trying to select second cell from `table-view` that trying to get value from array at `index 1`. but actually in to array there is no any value at `index 1`. That why Your app going to be crashed.

Please verify first using **NSLog** that your array is full fill according to your requirement or not.